# Nethack numpad commands

Tags: nethack, keyboard

The guidebook says that several additional keys can be used with the normal yuhjklbn movement keys to affect their behavior.

http://www.nethack.org/v360/Guidebook.html#_TOCentry_8

These include the m and g keys which can be used as prefixes.

Do these keys work with the numpad movement keys as well? Thanks.

Comment: Most folks would just try 'em out, but...

... Yeh, they work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do.  Internally, Nethack maps the number-pad movement keys and the letter-based movement keys to the exact same actions.